# Force change detection on all components in Angular 6 app

Tags: angular

I'm developing a simple grid component for an Angular 6 application. Basically, it consists of a main component, `app-grid`, which is an HTML table. Inside of it there are a determinate number of rows, that are another component (`app-row`). Finally, inside of each row, there are some cells that hold objects, and are inside another component: `app-cell`.

Here's a diagram of the architecture:

[image: Component architecture]

In an Angular-like template notation, the code for building the above components looks like:

```
<app-grid>
    <app-row *ngFor="let row of grid.rows; let i=index">
        <tr [ngClass]="{ 'row-highlighted' : row.highlighted }">
            <td> #{{ i }} </td>
            <app-cell *ngFor="let cell of row.cells">
                <td [ngClass]="{ 'cell-highlighted' : cell.highlighted }">
                </td>
            </app-cell>
        </tr>
    </app-row>
</app-grid>
```

The internal data structure to build this is stored in the `app-grid` component, and it looks like this:

```
grid = {
    title: 'SAMPLE GRID',        

    rows: [
        { 
          row_id: 20, 
          cells: [
            { cell_id: 201, cell_data: { DATA IN HERE } },
            { cell_id: 202, cell_data: { DATA IN HERE } },
            { cell_id: 203, cell_data: { DATA IN HERE } }
          ]
        },
        { 
          row_id: 30, 
          cells: [
            { cell_id: 301, cell_data: { DATA IN HERE } },
            { cell_id: 302, cell_data: { DATA IN HERE } },
            { cell_id: 303, cell_data: { DATA IN HERE } }
          ]
        }
    ]
};
```

To improve performance, both `app-row` and `app-cell` components are coded using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, so I trigger the change detection manually.

I'd like to be able to highlight an specific cell (for example, Cell [3, 2] in the picture above) and the row that contains it. To do it, I simply add an special class to the `<tr>` of the `app-row` and the `<td>` of the wanted `app-cell`, as you can see in the code sample above.

The problem I'm having is that the `<tr>` style is immediately applied so the row is highlighted, but the cell doesn't apply the style until I interact with it (for example, if I hover it). For doing it, I've created a method in the `app-grid` component with the following pseudo-code:

```
highlightRowAndCell(row_id, cell_id) {

    Search 'grid.rows' for a row with 'row_id' identifier;

    If found
        Set row.highlighted to true;
        Search 'row.cells' in the found row for a cell with 'cell_id' identifier;

        If found     
            Set cell.highlighted to true;

        // FORCE CHANGE DETECTION
        this.appRef.tick();

        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Neither `appRef.tick()` nor `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` update the cell style, but the row's is immediately changed. If I hover the cell, then the style is applied.

How could I tell Angular to update the view of the affected components (or all of them, it doesn't matter)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As far I know change Detection is for playing with data and data change. So this will not be a better approach for this purpose.

better to you `[ngClass]="{someCondition: 'someClass'}"` or [ngStyle] and bind it to some variable.

Comment: Hi, I've added the `[ngClass]` to the `app-cell` component but nothing changed. The class is visually shown only if I interact with the cell (f.i. hovering it).

Comment: How are you changing the variable.? That is the important thing to note onPush.

if you are changing nested property of array or object then it will not work

Comment: `arr = [a, b,c]`, then in that case it should be `arr[0]=10; arr = [...arr]`

Comment: and similary for object

Comment: This is what I do when I find the cell I want to highlight: `row.cells[i].highlighted = true`. Also, now I pass the `highlighted` property to the `app-cell` component: `<app-cell [highlighted]="cell.highlighted">` but still works the same way.

Comment: I doubt change detection will work if you change model like this.

Comment: I know you have implemented your task. It knowing this will help you.

for example if you have binding in view `<comp-a [someAtt]=obj.a.b"></comp-a>` then in model you have to `obj.a.b = 10;` and then `obj = Object.assign({}, obj);`

Comment: angular does not watches for nested object in this case

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a performance problem that prompted you to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? I think the much more common use case for that is for input controls, where you have a very specific event where you expect to trigger the change detection.

In your case, there isn't really such an event and I would rather forego the complexity altogether by using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`. It works really well for most use cases.

Also, if you are going to trigger change detection for all components, then you're not getting any benefit from the push model anyway - in fact, your performance will very likely be worse.

Comment: Hi, I switched to the `OnPush` strategy because the application works A LOT faster with grids of 200+ rows. I only trigger the change detection in few cases, for example, when an object is added to a cell so it's not a big issue for me.

Comment: @Fel If you're expecting that much data in a grid, it is worth considering the impact of DOM manipulation as well. For each `<tr>`, there is a DOM insert operation and another one for each `<td>` and even more if you have tags nested within those. While JavaScript is more than capable of handling more data, DOM manipulations are slow and memory intensive. Mobile devices with their restricted RAM simply doesn't cope, even with `OnPush`. My solution was to implement paging on the grid instead.

Comment: I was also worried about these performance issues. So far, the performance is really good for big grids up to 250 rows (which is twice the size we're expecting in an intensive use scenario), but in the future I want to implement pagination or even virtualization to this component to avoid being so memory intensive.

Answer (score 0):

All primitive types are passed by value. Objects, arrays, and functions are also passed by value

So in order to trigger a change detection in our component, we need to change the object reference.

```
highlightRowAndCell(row_id, cell_id) {

    Search 'grid.rows' for a row with 'row_id' identifier;

    If found
        //Set row.highlighted to true;
        this.row={
        highlighted=true;
         }
        Search 'row.cells' in the found row for a cell with 'cell_id' identifier;

        If found     
           // Set cell.highlighted to true;
           this.cell={highlighted=true}
}
```

Ref:https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Answer (score 0):

The `app-row` component has the `<tr>` element of the rows and the `<td>` of the cells, as stated above, so it's ideal to set the highlighted visual style to both row and cell. As I told before, I use a method (`highlightRowAndCell`) in the `app-grid` component to apply the visual style to the appropriate row and cell. The problem is that when I set `row.highlighted = true` and `cell.highlighted = true`, Angular doesn't detect these changes because they are properties of objects inside an array. So, to force it detecting the changes, I've added the following `@Input` to the `app-row` component:

**app-grid.component.html template:**

```
<app-row [...]
  [highlighted]="row.highlighted">
</app-row>
```

**app-row.component.ts:**

```
export class AppRowComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  [...]

  @Input() highlighted: boolean;

  [...]
}
```

Now, running `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` in the `highlightRowAndCell` method inside the `app-grid` component makes Angular refresh the affected `app-row` and the styles are applied immediately.